# Upgrade path for legacy device driver code (DriverStudio) to Win10 64-bit?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, driver

**tl;dr:** Device driver written in NuMega DriverStudio for Win95 to be upgraded to Win10 64-bit. What's the easiest path?

We have a very old product line, which is still selling well. One dll, accessing a UART in a way normal serial handlers can not (to support an even older protocol for another company's products), was made back when the product was first released - for Windows 98! Ever since, it has been working flawless (on 32-bit machines). Therefore, the code has never been touched since it's initial creation!!  (This is based on the memory of a few of my colleagues who were around at the time). The only source I have been able to find is from 2001, although one file dates back to 1998.
The driver type is WDM

Now Microsoft have stopped providing 32-bit versions of Windows 10, and customers have started asking for a 64-bit version of our software, so I landed the task of figuring out how easiest to fix it - and support win7 through to Win10, 64-bit.

However the DriverStudio from NuMega was discontinued shortly after the company was purchased by Compuware (and they have lost all knowledge of it!), and even if we were able to find an old version (latest is from 2002), it's unlikely that it's going to help us very much.

I've been searching the web, but haven't found anything giving any suggestions to what the then users of DriverStudio did to upgrade their drivers.
At the time, Jungo WinDriver were an alternative that most people didn't consider to use for 'real' drivers, but perhaps times have changed?

Any advice on how to upgrade this driver code as easy as possible will be highly appreciated.

Comment: hard to say something without view code of driver. what this is type of driver ? wdm ? at all strange - you say that same binary file run on win95 and on windows nt (x86) line ?

Comment: I have to say, I am honestly surprised at the sheer competence of Microsoft to keep such ancient cruft working. Windows 95 may have been Win32 at the application level, but it had an entirely old driver model (VXD, IIRC). Windows NT had its own drivers, and with Vista that was changed again. And yet those W95 drivers still work, 22 years later? Amazing. Equally amazing, how does that UART connect to a modern CPU? W95 dates back to plain old PCI, But TBH it sounds like you face a full rewrite from scratch - no easy way out.

Comment: @RbMm Updated the question. Yes the driver model is WDM, which I realized means it must have been released for Win98. I do nok know exactly which versions of windows has been used by our users. Certainly Win98, XP, Win7, Win8 and Win10.

Comment: @MSalters You are right, I realized my mistake since it's a WDM type of driver, which was introduced in Win98. So it's 'only' 19 years.